# jquery Datepicker not calling blur function if clicked on iframe

Tags: datepicker, ckeditor, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a page in which I have a date field and a CKeditor textarea(which creates an iframe at the textarea place) . On date picker I have defined a blur function to check date validity, which works correctly.

However, the issue is when I click on a datepicker field the calendar popup gets generated then I enter a invalid date and then click on inside ckeditor , the calendar remains open however focus gets lost but still the blur function doesn't get called. Hence invalid date goes to server. (I need client side validation for this date field) [image].

```
$(function(){
    $(".dateClass").datepicker({
        changeMonth : true,
        changeYear : true,
        yearRange: "-10:+10",
        dateFormat : "dd/mm/yy",
        buttonText : "Choose",
        showOtherMonths : true,
        selectOtherMonths : true            
    });



    $(".dateClass").blur(function(){
       if(this.value!=undefined && this.value!=null && this.value.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '')!=''){
            if(!isDateValid(this.value) && calendarOpen==0){
                alert('Please enter a valid date in dd/mm/yyyy format');
                this.focus();
            }
       }
    });
});
```

CKeditor is actually embedding an iframe in the page.
How do I call blur function when user clicks on date field and then on iframe ??

Answer (score 2):

thnx I got it to work by doing a way around

```
document.onfocusout = function(e){ //for IE8 and lesser 
    if( e === undefined ){
        //keeping validations here
     }
}

$(window).blur( function(e){ //for other browsers –
  if( e !== undefined ){
        //keeping validations here
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use onSelect for your required situation as

$(".dateClass").datepicker({
 changeMonth : true, changeYear : true,
 yearRange: "-10:+10", dateFormat : "dd/mm/yy", 
buttonText : "Choose", showOtherMonths : true,
 selectOtherMonths : true ,
onSelect: function(dateText, inst) { var date = $(this).val(); var time = $('#time').val(); alert('on select triggered'); 
}
});

Sorry for unformated code.
Hope it will help
http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-datepicker-onblur

Comment: actually the date field is editable hence onSelect won't get called if user enters manually...

Comment: Ok agreed. Please use live event as http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-datepicker-onblur

Comment: thnx I got it to work by doing a way around 
    document.onfocusout //for IE8 and lesser 
    $(window).blur //for other browsers